# Get all Dynamic DIV contents in ASPX Content Page

Tags: html, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Update Selection
    </title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>      

    <form id="aspnetForm" runat="server">
        
        <asp:Button ID="mybtntext" runat="server" Text="Button div" />

            <div class="container">
                <h2></h2>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">

                        <div class="header-prod-line">
                            <h4 class="text-center">Select Product Type</h4>
                            <h6 class="text-center">Confirm selection of product type below</h6>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_PanelLevel" class="panel-body">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        Very Important
                                <div id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_maindiv1" class="ui-widget-vi">
                                    <div class='column'>
                                        <div class='portlet'>
                                            <div class='portlet-header' value='First Cost'>First Cost</div>
                                            <div class='portlet-content'>(Lower) initial equipment cost</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class='portlet'>
                                            <div class='portlet-header' value='Energy Efficiency'>Energy Efficiency</div>
                                            <div class='portlet-content'>(Higher) cooling capacity per input power consumed.</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class='portlet'>
                                            <div class='portlet-header' value='Footprint'>Footprint</div>
                                            <div class='portlet-content'>(Smaller) equipment plan area (length x width).</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class='portlet'>
                                            <div class='portlet-header' value='Height'>Height</div>
                                            <div class='portlet-content'>(Lower) overall equipment height after installation.</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class='portlet'>
                                            <div class='portlet-header' value='Weight'>Weight</div>
                                            <div class='portlet-content'>(Lower) shipping weight, heaviest section weight, and/or operating weight.</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class='portlet'>
                                            <div class='portlet-header' value='Sound'>Sound</div>
                                            <div class='portlet-content'>(Lower) equipment sound levels.</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class='portlet'>
                                            <div class='portlet-header' value='Maintenance Ease'>Maintenance Ease</div>
                                            <div class='portlet-content'>(Lower) maintenance time and complexity.</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        Important
                                <div id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_maindiv2" class="ui-widget-i">
                                    <div class='column'>
                                        <div class='portlet'>
                                            <div class='portlet-header' value='Operating Cost'>Operating Cost</div>
                                            <div class='portlet-content'>(Lower) annual energy, water, and maintenance costs.</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class='portlet'>
                                            <div class='portlet-header' value='Corrosion Resistance'>Corrosion Resistance</div>
                                            <div class='portlet-content'>(Longer) equipment life over a broad range of water qualities and environmental conditions.</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        Somewhat Important
                                <div id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_maindiv3" class="ui-widget-si">
                                    <div class='column'>
                                        <div class='portlet'>
                                            <div class='portlet-header' value='Installation Ease'>Installation Ease</div>
                                            <div class='portlet-content'>(Lower) installation time and complexity.</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class='portlet'>
                                            <div class='portlet-header' value='Redundancy'>Redundancy</div>
                                            <div class='portlet-content'>(Higher) capacity available in the event of unit or component failure.</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class='portlet'>
                                            <div class='portlet-header' value='Cold Weather Operation'>Cold Weather Operation</div>
                                            <div class='portlet-content'>(Lower) operational challenges during freezing conditions.</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        Not Important
                                <div id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_maindiv4" class="ui-widget-ni">
                                    <div class='column'>
                                        <div class='portlet'>
                                            <div class='portlet-header' value='Indor Ducted Installation'>Indor Ducted Installation</div>
                                            <div class='portlet-content'></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center spacing-bottom">
                        <input type="submit" name="_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:btnNext" value="Next" id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnNext" class="btn btn-primary-spx" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center spacing-bottom">
                        <input type="submit" name="_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:Button1" value="Back" id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_Button1" class="btn btn-previous-spx" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:VIhfLevels" id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_VIhfLevels" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:IhfLevels" id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_IhfLevels" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:SIhfLevels" id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_SIhfLevels" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:NIhfLevels" id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_NIhfLevels" />

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
    </form>
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <a id="_ctl0_hlCompany" href="https://spxcooling.com" target="_blank">&copy;2021 SPX Cooling Technologies, Inc. All rights reserved.</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    
</body>
</html>

    <script>
    
    <%--    $('# <%= txtName.ClientID %>')--%>
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#mybtntext").click(function () {
    
                let output = $('.col-md-3 > div').map((i, c) => ({
                    [c.id]: $(c).find('.portlet-header').map((i, p) => $(p).text()).get()
                })).get();
    
                console.log(output);
                alert(output);
            //  var result = {};
            //  alert($("[id$=_maindiv1]").attr("id"));
            //$("div[id^=maindiv]").each(function () {
            //  var key = $(this).attr('id');
            //  alert(key);
            //  result[key] = $(this).find('.portlet-header').map(function () {
            //      return $(this).text();
            //  })
            //      .get()
            //      .join(',');
            //});
            //console.log(result);
            //alert(result);
        });
    
        });
    </script>
```

> In the above aspx content page I tried to get only all div Id's of
> Maindiv => portlet-header contents only My desired output is that I
> need to extract all 'Portlet-header' class contents only from 4 divs
> like  "maindiv1", "maindiv2", "maindiv3", "maindiv4" as below
> "maindiv1" - Energy_Efficiency,Maintenance_Ease, Cold_Weather_Operation
> "maindiv2" - First_Cost, Operating_cost, Footprint, Height, Corrosion_Resistance
> "maindiv3" - Weight, Installation-Ease, Redundancy
> "maindiv4" - Indor_Ducted_Installation, Water_Usage

Comment: Your current code is giving that output what does work here ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var maindiv1 = [];
var maindiv2 = [];
var maindiv3 = [];
var maindiv4 = [];

$('.portlet-header').each(function(index, key) {
  var parent = $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('id')
  var res = parent.split("_");
  if (res[3] == 'maindiv1') {
    maindiv1.push($(this).attr('value'));
  } else if (res[3] == 'maindiv2') {
    maindiv2.push($(this).attr('value'));
  } else if (res[3] == 'maindiv3') {
    maindiv3.push($(this).attr('value'));
  } else {
    maindiv4.push($(this).attr('value'));
  }
});

console.log(maindiv1);
console.log(maindiv2);
console.log(maindiv3);
console.log(maindiv4);

var div1 = {};
var div2 = {};
var div3 = {};
var div4 = {};

for (var i = 0; i < maindiv1.length; i++) {
  div1[i] = {
    div: 'maindiv1',
    portletheader: maindiv1[i],
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < maindiv2.length; i++) {
  div2[i] = {
    div: 'maindiv2',
    portletheader: maindiv2[i],
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < maindiv3.length; i++) {
  div3[i] = {
    div: 'maindiv3',
    portletheader: maindiv3[i],
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < maindiv4.length; i++) {
  div4[i] = {
    div: 'maindiv4',
    portletheader: maindiv4[i],
  }
}

console.log(div1);
console.log(div2);
console.log(div3);
console.log(div4);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="aspnetForm" runat="server">

  <asp:Button ID="mybtntext" runat="server" Text="Button div" />

  <div class="container">
    <h2></h2>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="header-prod-line">
          <h4 class="text-center">Select Product Type</h4>
          <h6 class="text-center">Confirm selection of product type below</h6>
        </div>

        <div id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_PanelLevel" class="panel-body">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                Very Important
                <div id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_maindiv1" class="ui-widget-vi">
                  <div class='column'>
                    <div class='portlet'>
                      <div class='portlet-header' value='First Cost'>First Cost</div>
                      <div class='portlet-content'>(Lower) initial equipment cost</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='portlet'>
                      <div class='portlet-header' value='Energy Efficiency'>Energy Efficiency</div>
                      <div class='portlet-content'>(Higher) cooling capacity per input power consumed.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='portlet'>
                      <div class='portlet-header' value='Footprint'>Footprint</div>
                      <div class='portlet-content'>(Smaller) equipment plan area (length x width).</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='portlet'>
                      <div class='portlet-header' value='Height'>Height</div>
                      <div class='portlet-content'>(Lower) overall equipment height after installation.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='portlet'>
                      <div class='portlet-header' value='Weight'>Weight</div>
                      <div class='portlet-content'>(Lower) shipping weight, heaviest section weight, and/or operating weight.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='portlet'>
                      <div class='portlet-header' value='Sound'>Sound</div>
                      <div class='portlet-content'>(Lower) equipment sound levels.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='portlet'>
                      <div class='portlet-header' value='Maintenance Ease'>Maintenance Ease</div>
                      <div class='portlet-content'>(Lower) maintenance time and complexity.</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                Important
                <div id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_maindiv2" class="ui-widget-i">
                  <div class='column'>
                    <div class='portlet'>
                      <div class='portlet-header' value='Operating Cost'>Operating Cost</div>
                      <div class='portlet-content'>(Lower) annual energy, water, and maintenance costs.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='portlet'>
                      <div class='portlet-header' value='Corrosion Resistance'>Corrosion Resistance</div>
                      <div class='portlet-content'>(Longer) equipment life over a broad range of water qualities and environmental conditions.</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                Somewhat Important
                <div id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_maindiv3" class="ui-widget-si">
                  <div class='column'>
                    <div class='portlet'>
                      <div class='portlet-header' value='Installation Ease'>Installation Ease</div>
                      <div class='portlet-content'>(Lower) installation time and complexity.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='portlet'>
                      <div class='portlet-header' value='Redundancy'>Redundancy</div>
                      <div class='portlet-content'>(Higher) capacity available in the event of unit or component failure.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='portlet'>
                      <div class='portlet-header' value='Cold Weather Operation'>Cold Weather Operation</div>
                      <div class='portlet-content'>(Lower) operational challenges during freezing conditions.</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                Not Important
                <div id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_maindiv4" class="ui-widget-ni">
                  <div class='column'>
                    <div class='portlet'>
                      <div class='portlet-header' value='Indor Ducted Installation'>Indor Ducted Installation</div>
                      <div class='portlet-content'></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="text-center spacing-bottom">
        <input type="submit" name="_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:btnNext" value="Next" id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnNext" class="btn btn-primary-spx" />
      </div>
      <div class="text-center spacing-bottom">
        <input type="submit" name="_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:Button1" value="Back" id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_Button1" class="btn btn-previous-spx" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:VIhfLevels" id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_VIhfLevels" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:IhfLevels" id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_IhfLevels" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:SIhfLevels" id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_SIhfLevels" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:NIhfLevels" id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_NIhfLevels" />

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <a id="_ctl0_hlCompany" href="https://spxcooling.com" target="_blank">&copy;2021 SPX Cooling Technologies, Inc. All rights reserved.</a>
  </div>
</footer>
```

This is what I found out.

Comment: Thanks Bernhard, But I want to group the contents from each div name, like maindiv1, maindiv2, maindiv3 and maindiv4, I've tried but the div id is not static, that is where I'm having the issue. If you provide the result as JSON also good.

Comment: I just want to make more clear, I need all theclass='portlet-header' contents from all the div's by looping _ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_maindiv1, _ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_maindiv2, _ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_maindiv3, _ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_maindiv4

Comment: updated my answer. Not perfect but you get json Strings for each portlet-header